# What are the system default values for padding in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

In documentation, there is a description of `length` parameter in `padding(_:_:)` method.

> The amount to inset this view on each edge. If `nil`,the amount is the
> system default amount.

What is default "system default amount" value? If I understand correctly, user can change this amount, e.g. by changing display zoom in settings.

Comment: It is different everywhere, on different platforms, between different UI elements, so you can either use it as-is, or specify yours if want to know explicit values.

Answer (score 2):

This was already answered by the user [emreoktem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1722716/emreoktem) in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65368402/what-is-the-default-value-of-the-padding-modifier-in-swift).

> As far as I understood from Apple's documentation, there's no standard value and it's calculated based on some criteria by Apple. So, it may be different for different devices, accessibility settings of user, if user is using the app in side-by-side mode on iPad, etc...

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/padding(_:_:)) is the documentation:

The set of edges along which to pad this view; if nil the specified or system-calculated amount is applied to all edges.